# Create a new column based on timestamp value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column "local_time" with 24 hr format in my table.I want to create a new column with values AM ,PM based on the timestamp .

Example

```
     Local_time 

2018-06-29 10:57:59
2018-06-29 12:17:42
2018-07-02 15:46:09
```

Expected

```
 Local_time                    day_time

2018-06-29 10:57:59               AM
2018-06-29 12:17:42               PM
2018-07-02 15:46:09               PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `case when` and compare with time

```
select Local_time,
case when EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Local_time)<12 then 'AM' else 'PM' end as day_time 
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use to_char conversion with `PM` or `AM` :

```
create table tab( local_time timestamp );
insert into tab values(now());
insert into tab values(('2018-06-29 10:57:59')::timestamp);

SELECT local_time, 
       to_char(local_time,'AM') day_time1,
       to_char(local_time,'PM') day_time2
  FROM tab;

local_time                  day_time1   day_time2
2018-08-01T22:17:52.599662Z    PM          PM
2018-06-29T10:57:59Z           AM          AM
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9692f/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `extract` to get `hour` number then use `CASE WHEN`.

```
SELECT local_time, 
     (CASE WHEN extract(hour from local_time) < 12 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM' END) day_time
FROM t
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f2cad/3)

**[Results]**:

```
|           local_time | day_time |
|----------------------|----------|
| 2018-06-29T10:57:59Z |       AM |
| 2018-06-29T12:17:42Z |       PM |
| 2018-07-02T15:46:09Z |       PM |
```